# Are there examples of neural networks (used for control) implemented on a FPGA or on a neurochip?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, neuromorphic-engineering, control-theory

Greetings to all respected colleagues!

I want to consult on the use of [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)s and [neurochips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromorphic_engineering). I plan to use it in my laboratory project for programming control systems on neural networks.

In my work, there are a lot of applications of neural networks, and I became interested in their programming on FPGAs and neurochips.
But I don’t know a single example of a really made and working laboratory prototype in which a neural network is implemented on an FPGA or on a neurochip and controls something. If someone shares the link, I would carefully study it.

Comment: I mean there are a lot of people working on these topics, a quick Google search can give you many results, what is it that you are exactly looking for?

Comment: Because I'm a beginner, I need a good tutorial.

Comment: That's pretty broad. FPGA based NN is nothing but mostly binary valued NNs, only algorithms will probably be given in the research papers. There's no real need for tutoring I guess (if you already know how to implement verilog codes on FPGA)

Comment: I have never previously used either a FPGA or neurochips. Therefore, I do not know how to program on them.

Comment: Well then you have to learn a lot. You first need to learn both NN and FPGA programming (if you want to implement in FPGA), or there exists ZISC processors which are directly programmable for pattern recognition. For that you require to learn its instruction set (which will be probably vaialble in its website).

Comment: Good start for me would be a tutorial on programming in FPGA or Neurochip of neural network control of motor speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumption

In this answer it is assumed that with "neurochips" you mean chips made (using neuromorphic engineering) for neuromphic computing.

## Related example

From what I currently understand from [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06061.pdf) neuromorphic chips, in particular the TrueNorth chip, are being used (or emulated) for embedded systems related signals processing.

## Doubt

The signal processing performed by these (emulated) neuromorphic chips might be part of real-life applications involving control systems.